# Talend: use Google Spreadsheets as Input and Output

Tags: google-sheets, salesforce, etl, talend

I'm using Talend for several ETL-jobs. Main focus on inserting and updating data defined in local Excel files to Salesforce. Excel and Salesforce are used as Input- and Output-Connections massively.

This works like a charm!

Now instead of Excel I need to use **Google Spreadsheets** as data inputs/outputs. Just manually download as Excel isn't good enough. Reason: I need a highspeed repeatable process executed thousands of times bi-directional. Uploading/Downloading XLS/CSV is not an option.

As an unfortunate, my researches concluded that there is **NO** Google spreadsheet connector available. I found this legacy-project which seems to be abandoned: https://code.google.com/p/google-talend-components/ - it is outdated from Talend-side as well as from Google (old API versions).

One other thing I've seen, is that Talend comes with Google Big Data Support: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BK6G3sTmwVE - Also Google Big Data might be somehow connectable to Google Spreadsheet - but I wasn't able to figure out how. Is this easy or hard? How to start? What to read?

I need to know if there is **any viable approach** to read and write data with Talend from and to Google-Spreadsheet.

Alternatively is there an other ETL-tool like Talend which has connectors to Google Spreadsheet AND Salesforce out-of-the-box?

Comment: I will try to reproduce this component using new API version, but not sure when it will be ready for test.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a direct google docs connector in Talend, no.  But you can do what you are looking to do if you think of the problem a little differently.  It sounds like you need to read and write to spreadsheets then upload/download from google.  Lets take each problem separately.

**Upload/Download**

- Google storage.  If you need to upload and download files from google Talend has excellent integration with their API.  As you mentioned, Talend --> Big Data has components to interact with Google Storage.  This type of storage is primary meant as back end storage for an application.
- In Talend under Cloud-->Google Drive there are components to upload and download from Google Drive.  Google Drive is primarily meant as Chrome app and has direct integration with Google Docs.

**Writing to Google Docs**

Regarding your need to interact with google docs, you do not need any special components for this.  Google docs can utilize csv and Excel formats.  If you create and modify your documents in Talend using the standard file interaction components ( delimited, Excel, etc.) you can upload and download these documents using one of the two methods I described above (Google Storage or Drive) depending on what type of storage you are using.